# App Path incorrectly set as REG_SZ

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have *Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1* with *PowerShell 4.0*. Under this key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\PowerShell.exe
```

I found these values

```
(Default)  REG_SZ  %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe
Path       REG_SZ  %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

[The problem](http://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/Z7edBjD5w14) here is the type is `REG_SZ` instead of `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, so the
`%SystemRoot%` is never evaluated. I have installed all important Windows
updates, but not all optional updates. Is an optional update available to fix
this, or does it require manually editing the registry?

Comment: Please install ALL updates and verify the problem still exists.  You shouldn't have to modify the registery to fix this.

Comment: @Ramhound after installing all optional updates the values are unchanged